# Difference between different constructions of the same phrasal verb

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between the following 2 sentences or they are same?

> I found out its secrets.
>
> I found its secrets out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Here we are talking about a **separable** phrasal verb. If the object is a noun, you can put it after the particle or before it. If the object is a pronoun, it must be put before the particle:

> I found out a secret. = I found the secret out.
>
> She found out the truth. = She found the truth out.

BUT

> I/she found **it** out.